# Are there "soft" assertions in NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, assertion

Are there such a concept as "soft assertions" in NUnit? If so, how do I make use of it?

**Background and details of what I mean with "soft assertions":**

In a set of acceptance tests I want to verify that a form is filled out correctly. Currently, I do this with the following specflow step:

```
Then The new note form is filled out as follows
         | Label       | Value    |
         | First Name  | Jon      |
         | Last name   | Skeet    |
         | Title       | Cool Kat |
```

which is implemented something like this:

```
[Then(@"The new note form is filled out as follows")]
public void ThenTheNewNoteFormIsFilledOutAsFollows(Table table)
{
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var name = row["Label"];
        var value = row["Value"];

        switch (name)
        {
            case "First Name":
                // Page is part of our automation framework - Page.FirstName is 
                // simply an abstraction over getting the value of the 
                // <input name="FirstName" />
                Assert.That(Page.FirstName, Is.EqualTo(value), 
                            "Incorrect first name: Expected {0}, was {1}", 
                            value, Page.FirstName);
                continue;
            case "Last Name":
                Assert.That(Page.LastName, Is.EqualTo(value), 
                            "Incorrect first name: Expected {0}, was {1}", 
                            value, Page.LastName);
                continue;
            // similar cases for the other properties
        }
    }
}
```

This works, in that it gives us correct test results (pass/fail) and with error messages that show what went wrong. However, because test execution is aborted when an `Assert` fails, only the first failing form value is reported; if, say, the form was empty, only `First Name` in the above example would be reported missing, and I'd have to re-run the test to see that `Last Name` was also missing.

Since these are browser automation tests, runtimes are quite long, and it would be nice to get a test failure that reports *all* incorrect form elements, and not just the first one.

Is this possible with NUnit?

---

To readers who want to object "Don't do this - a unit test should just test one thing":

Yes, I know - but your argument is invalid, because this *isn't* a unit test. It's an acceptance test, which tests that the *entire stack* is working. We happen to use the NUnit for designing and executing these tests, but that doesn't make them unit tests.

Comment: Of course, I could accomplish this manually by collecting error messages, asserting that the collection is empty or else show the messages, but I figure this is something that a unit testing framework *should* do for me...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2834717/1698557) has some options, though it doesn't look like anything is built in.

Comment: plus one, but I think close as dup is appropriate: The [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14207679/321013) seemingly at least provides a way to do it yourself.

Comment: We are planning on adding this to NUnit 3.0. If you want to track the progress, it is [Issue 391](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/391)

Answer (score 1):

Assert.Multiple is now available https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Multiple-Asserts

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I've implemented that by catching the exceptions, putting them in a list, and then asserting at the end of the method. It's hacky, but it works. I wish I had the code handy, but basically I wrote a wrapper around Assert that would catch and collect. I just grabbed the assert code from Nunit and wrote the wrapper around it.
Not as nice as a built in answer, but it worked well. It kept tests clean, but the wrapper was a lot of boilerplate.