# Handling tables in c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onclick="" style="width: 1345px;">

  <tbody>

    <tr id="item_tcm:222-382904-131104" title="2. Publish to WIP (tcm:222-382904-131104)" class="item even" c:drawn="true">
      <td class="col0 icon odd" value="T131104L0P0">
        <div class="icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;/WebUI/Editors/CME/Themes/Carbon2/icon_v7.1.0.66.55_.png?name=T131104L0P0&amp;size=16&quot;);"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="col1 even">
        <div class="text">2.&nbsp;Publish&nbsp;to&nbsp;WIP</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col2 odd">
        <div class="text">JH&nbsp;Anchor&nbsp;link&nbsp;2</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col3 even">
        <div class="text">S070&nbsp;Public&nbsp;Site&nbsp;US&nbsp;English</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col4 odd" value="2015-12-23T14:41:04">
        <div class="text">12/23/2015 2:41 PM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col5 even">
        <div class="text">NT&nbsp;AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col6 odd" value="">
        <div class="text">
          <span style="color: #f00"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col7 even" value="16">
        <div class="text">Suspended</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col8 odd">
        <div class="text">NT&nbsp;AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col9 even">
        <div class="text">Publishing&nbsp;Failed</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_tcm:222-382901-131104" title="2. Publish to WIP (tcm:222-382901-131104)" class="item even" c:drawn="true">
      <td class="col0 icon odd" value="T131104L0P0">
        <div class="icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;/WebUI/Editors/CME/Themes/Carbon2/icon_v7.1.0.66.55_.png?name=T131104L0P0&amp;size=16&quot;);"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="col1 even">
        <div class="text">2.&nbsp;Publish&nbsp;to&nbsp;WIP</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col2 odd">
        <div class="text">JH_anchor&nbsp;link</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col3 even">
        <div class="text">S070&nbsp;Public&nbsp;Site&nbsp;US&nbsp;English</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col4 odd" value="2015-12-23T14:17:51">
        <div class="text">12/23/2015 2:17 PM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col5 even">
        <div class="text">NT&nbsp;AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col6 odd" value="">
        <div class="text">
          <span style="color: #f00"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col7 even" value="16">
        <div class="text">Suspended</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col8 odd">
        <div class="text">NT&nbsp;AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</div>
      </td>
      <td class="col9 even">
        <div class="text">Publishing&nbsp;Failed</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    .....
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have collection of rows. Inside each row i have 10 columns(td). I want to iterate to each row. For each row I want to get the 8th and 10 th column.
Note :- The test case will get **Fail** if the 8th column value is "Suspended" and 10th column value is "Publishing Failed" or else the test case would get **Pass**

I tried the below logic

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table"));
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var item in tableRow)
{

}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed further. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: so when stepping through the code using the debugger .. what do you have for values of tableRow as well as item if you were to put a breakpoint on the first `{` are you familiar with how to debug your own code..? sounds like you need to tell us more information about what you are or are not seeing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your logic is good:

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table"));
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> rowTD;
foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
{
   rowTD = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

   if(rowTD.Count > 9)
   {
      if(rowTD[8].Text.Equals("Suspended") && rowTD[10].Text.Equals("Publishing Failed");
      //test failed
   }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine..Thanks for spending your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you would just try to find the rows having the 8th column value  "Suspended" and 10th column value "Publishing Failed":

```
IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("//table//tr[td[8]/div = 'Suspended' and td[10]/div = 'Publishing Failed']"));
```

Then, you can fail the test if `rows` list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in tableRow)
{
    IWebElement column7 = item.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='col7']"));
    IWebElement column9 = item.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='col9']"));

    if (column7.Text.Equals("Suspended") && column9.Text.Equals("Publishing Failed"))
        Assert.Fail("Failed because column8 is 'Suspended' and column10 is 'Publishing Failed'");
    else
        Assert.Pass();
}
```

Please note that this code will stop testing when it has found the "Suspended" and "Publishing Failed". If you want to continue testing until the final row in table, you have to use multiple assertions. [NUnit, is it possible to continue executing test after Assert fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834717/nunit-is-it-possible-to-continue-executing-test-after-assert-fails)

Comment: We not not using Assert function. Instead we will be returning the value to compare it with the XML file

Comment: So you can replace replace the assertion statements with return statement.