# Is multiple assertions execution is possible inside one test case using NUNIT 3?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, nunit-3.0

in Nunit 2 there was an attribute class [MultiAssert] which was responsible for doing multiple assertions without skipping the assertions if the preceding assertion failed.

is there any substitute available for the same in NUNIT 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NUnit, is it possible to continue executing test after Assert fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834717/nunit-is-it-possible-to-continue-executing-test-after-assert-fails)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Assertions are planned, but not yet implemented in NUnit 3, see the issue below.

[github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/391](http://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/391)

As far as I'm aware, they've never been possible in NUnit 2 either - I could be wrong there though. Are you perhaps thinking of a different framework?

Comment: I am not sure because last time i checked the content for MultiAssert was available in Nunit 2.6 but now that reference is not available. anyway thanks for the reference.