# NUnit Retry not working for the below scenario

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, parameterized, nunit-3.0

I tried the below code for `NUnit(3.13.2)` retry on the test method for which the test got failed and it displayed

> Expected: No Exception to be thrown and But was ERROR

here and then it is not retrying the test again. Here is my sample test method:

```
[Test, Retry(2), Category("Test")]
[Description("Verifies the URL")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(ExcelStatic), "Method Name", new object[] { "TestData\SampleTests2.xlsx", "sampletesttab"})] 

public void Test2_URL( string url, string application) {

    Assert.That(
        () => UtilitiesPage.URL(driver, appUrl), Throws.Nothing
    ); // This method is present in the other libraries
```

Please help

Comment: btw: why not use `Assert.DoesNotThrow(...)`?

Comment: the answer to your question: if an NUnit test assert fails at any point, it will not proceed - it will always cancel at that point.

Comment: maybe you can find a way to continue in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834717/nunit-is-it-possible-to-continue-executing-test-after-assert-fails